# Creating a toolbar button that runs a Macro in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, toolbar

I've created a MACRO in visual studio 2010 that builds my project and attaches it to several processes. Unfortunately, unlike in vs2008, I can't add it to a toolbar so I can run it with a press of a button; after looking it up I found out the guys at Microsoft left the option of adding a macro button out of vs2010:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/vsx/thread/87455de6-2a7d-42dd-b51f-ddd442c3e3fd
Am I wrong and there is a way/workaround that can solve this?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible.  Tools + Customize, Commands tab, Toolbar radio button.  Use the combo to select the toolbar you want to change.  Add Command button, Categories = Macros, select the macro in the Command list.  Modify Selection to alter the button properties.

What you can't do is select an image for the new button.  That's indeed stunningly lame, looks like they just didn't have time to get it done.  You can add your vote to this [feedback article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533245/macros-added-to-toolbar-cant-have-images).  But surely on the todo list for the next version already.

Comment: I knew how to do that, but my problem was that I didn't see the macro in the command list. That was because the macro I created was in fact a Macro Module and not a Macro. After creating a new macro inside the Macro Module and copying the macro there, it was solved and I was able to see the macro in the command list. thanks anyway!

Comment: @Micky - Thank you!  Your explanation just helped me solve the same issue :-)

Comment: And I just noticed that it's extremely important to name the macro module the same in the file as it's name is shown in the macro explorer/ide tree view. If it's not the same name, then it also will not be listed